# Drawing circle on fingerprint image and delta

Tags: java, image-processing, fingerprint, fingerprinting

How can I draw a circle or x just to show on a delta point or core to show typical graph form by these finger print element. I mean how can I detect a core and delta in finger print image. I actually have a project where I collect finger prints from scanner as Image object and I want to analyse them such that I draw vertex and egdes on the Imag

Typical example is the image attached[image]

Comment: What framework? Or do you just want to update the image itself?

Comment: Thanks, I already got the Image as java.awt.image.BufferedImage; Though I got it from SecuGen scanner using their sdk

Comment: `how can I detect a core and delta in finger print image` Detecting Minutiae is not trivial to implement yourself. You might look at image processing tools like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), or biometric software to do the recognition for you, such as [NIST bioemetric image software](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm)

Comment: To do recorgnition is not the problem as this inclued feature of the scanner api. I just want to show the graph of these delta, core point

Answer (score 0):

Given a `BufferedImage` you can call `createGraphics()` to obtain a `Graphics2D` which you can then draw basic primitives to which will end up in your BufferedImage.

E.g. assuming you have :

```
BufferedImage fingerprint = readFingerPrint();
```

Then you can do:

```
Graphics2D gfx = fingerprint.createGraphics();
gfx.draw( new line2D.Double( x1, y1, x2, y2) );
gfx.draw( new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the problem is not how to use the graphics api but how to detect where I want to plot these curves. I mean how to detect delta or core in the image

Comment: Perhaps you could consider changing the title of your question from 'Drawing circle on fingerprint image and delta' which, especially when taken with your previous comment, 'To do recorgnition is not the problem .... I just want to show the graph of these delta, core point ' strongly suggest that this *is* about using the graphics API. Also, see true response from @copeg